# Overwrite json file after exiting app and relaunching

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to save a single int to a file in my Android project although i cant get my write function to work.

My JSON file:

```
{
  "user":
 {
   "userid":"0"
 }
}
```

My code:

```
public String getJsonFile() {
        String jsonLocation = "";
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("useriidd.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            jsonLocation = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonLocation;
}

public void jsonRead(){
    try {
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(getJsonFile());
        JSONObject sys = reader.getJSONObject("user");
        userid = Integer.parseInt(sys.getString("userid"));
    }
    catch (final JSONException e) {
        Log.e("asdasd", e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void jsonWrite(){
    try {
        JSONObject writer = new JSONObject(getJsonFile());
        JSONObject sys = writer.getJSONObject("user");
        sys.put("userid", Integer.toString(userid));
        Log.d("asdasd", getJsonFile());
    }
    catch (final JSONException e) {
        Log.e("asdasd", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I need the userid value to also be saved if i exit the app and relaunch it.

Answer (score 0):

You should store it in `Preferences`, `SharedPreferences` or in the file on external storage (SD card). You cannot (or should not) edit the assets in run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Declare on Class level

```
public static final String KEY = "key";
private String value = "you can place any value";
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

onCreate Method

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourMainActivity.this);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(KEY, value);
```

onResume Method

```
value = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY, "defaultValue");
```

You can also do this step on onPause Method

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putString(KEY, value);
```